# x-axis is pressed together

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, markdown, r-markdown

I'd like to create a markdown document out of my R script. I managed it to display different barplots, piecharts, a leaflet map and so on.

But it doesn't work with ggplot.

```
{r, eval=TRUE, echo=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

p <- qplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +
  xlab("wrong") +
  ylab("super") +
  geom_polygon(data=fortify(data1),
               aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), alpha=0.1, fill=NA, col="black", size=0.1) +
  geom_point(data = as.data.frame(data2),
            aes(x = coords.x1, y = coords.x2, color = pal1), shape=4, alpha=1)

p + theme(legend.position="right")
```

The plot looks totally fine if i export it with ggsave, but in the markdown the x axis is pressed together.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre] including YAML headers and using a random or built-in dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to work out your problems. However, you could try to change a few lines (each at a time) to see if it makes a difference. Particularly, I would remove the line `coord_fixed(ratio = 1) +` to see what happens. You could also try different `ratio` numbers as well to get what you want.
If this does not fix your problem, please provide a reproducible example data.